# Pass data from UITableViewCell by Button inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to pass the `PostList[indexPath.row].id` to another view controller by button, without select all of cell:

```
    class UserNewFeeds: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let Shamar_URL = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/jadeed/fetchtimeline.php")

    var PostList = Array<Feeds>()

    var refresh = UIRefreshControl()

    @IBOutlet weak var CollectionList: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        LoadNewFeeds()

        CollectionList.reloadData()

    }

    var FeedUser : String?

    @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
        CollectionList.reloadData()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return PostList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let Cell:NewFeedsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Feed", for: indexPath) as! NewFeedsCell

        Cell.Userimg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "User")
        Cell.Fullname.text = PostList[indexPath.row].name
        Cell.Username.text = PostList[indexPath.row].username
        Cell.DatePost.text = PostList[indexPath.row].date
        Cell.PostView.text = PostList[indexPath.row].body
        Cell.PostID.text = PostList[indexPath.row].id
        Cell.come.tag = indexPath.row
        Cell.come.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserNewFeeds.Connect), for: .touchUpInside)
        print(Cell.come.tag)
        return Cell
    }

    func Connect(_ sender: Any, event: Any, segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ID_Post", sender: sender)
        let touches = (event as AnyObject).allTouches!
        let touch = touches?.first!
        let currentTouchPosition = touch?.location(in: CollectionList)
        var indexPath = CollectionList.indexPathForRow(at: currentTouchPosition!)!

        if segue.identifier == "ID_Post" {
            let testCon = segue.destination as! UserComments
            testCon.id_post = PostList[indexPath.row].id
            print(PostList[indexPath.row].id!)
        }
        print("position:\(indexPath.row)")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        CollectionList.estimatedRowHeight = 220
        CollectionList.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func LoadNewFeeds() {

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: Shamar_URL! as URL)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error!)")
                return;
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                do {

                    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]

                    let parseJSON = myJSON
                    let PostList = parseJSON?["Timeline"] as! [[String:Any]]

                    DispatchQueue.global().sync {

                        self.PostList.removeAll()

                        for post in PostList {

                            self.PostList.append(Feeds(name: post["name"]! as! String , username: post["post_by"]! as! String , body: post["body"]! as! String , date: post["post_date"]! as! String, id: post["id_post"]! as! String))
                        }
                        self.CollectionList.reloadData()

                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            })

        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I am trying by this function but it failed:

```
func Connect(_ sender: Any, event: Any, segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ID_Post", sender: sender)
    let touches = (event as AnyObject).allTouches!
    let touch = touches?.first!
    let currentTouchPosition = touch?.location(in: CollectionList)
    var indexPath = CollectionList.indexPathForRow(at: currentTouchPosition!)!

    if segue.identifier == "ID_Post" {
        let testCon = segue.destination as! UserComments
        testCon.id_post = PostList[indexPath.row].id
        print(PostList[indexPath.row].id!)
    }
    print("position:\(indexPath.row)")
}
```

This is the error:

```
 2017-10-02 03:44:41.235 Al-Jadeed[31709:211436] -[UITouchesEvent identifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000f0400
2017-10-02 03:44:41.326 Al-Jadeed[31709:211436] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITouchesEvent identifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000f0400'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5edb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ac3d141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b65d134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b574840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5743b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Al-Jadeed                           0x000000010a46ddba _TFC9Al_Jadeed12UserNewFeeds7ConnectfTP_5eventP_5segueCSo17UIStoryboardSegue_T_ + 1850
    6   Al-Jadeed                           0x000000010a46e689 _TToFC9Al_Jadeed12UserNewFeeds7ConnectfTP_5eventP_5segueCSo17UIStoryboardSegue_T_ + 121
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c359d82 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c4de5ac -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c4de8c7 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c4dd802 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c8831f9 _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 5553
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c87e210 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1409
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c87dc43 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 484
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c87ce0a -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 274
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c3c8eea -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4092
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c375a84 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010cb595d4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010cb51532 __handleEventQueue + 1122
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b593c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5790cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5785ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b578016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001114f6a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010c358134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    25  Al-Jadeed                           0x000000010a4bed67 main + 55
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f73a65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you give us some details about the errors or the fail? Thank you

Comment: Not that I speak this language but if you want to encourage people to help you, please show some effort in your question, proper casing, punctuation, proper code formatting, as well as showing us what is the error that you see.

Comment: I apologize for these errors and the question method, I have fixed them with a clear error that appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cast is failing because you're sending the ViewController as the sender of the segue, not the button.

Change your `Connect` method to:

```
 func Connect(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ID_Post", sender: sender)
 }
```

And now change the selector of your button so it sends itself as an argument (and properly set the tag):

```
Cell.come.tag = indexPath.row
Cell.come.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UserNewFeeds.Connect(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: that's work , but still I can't pass the PostList[indexPath.row].id

Comment: I saw your edit now - don't get rid it of the prepareForSegue method, keep it, cast the sender to an UIButton and get it's tag. Then you'll be able to access the id using the tag instead of indexPath.row